# row_number in Apache Beam SQL

Tags: apache-beam, beam-sql

I'm trying to generate `row_number` using Apache Beam SQL with below code:

```java
PCollection<Row> rwrtg =
        PCollectionTuple.of(new TupleTag<>("trrtg"), rrtg)
                        .apply(SqlTransform.query("select appId, row_number() over (partition by appId order by rating asc) as issue_rank from trrtg"));
```

But getting below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot translate call ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY $t0 ORDER BY $t1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Could you please advise how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Beam SQL supports two Dialects:-

1. Beam Calcite - Details can be found [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/calcite/overview/#functions-and-operators) regarding supported operators.
2. ZetaSQL - Details can be found [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/zetasql/overview/#functions-and-operators) regarding supported operators

Both these dialects today don't support row_number() analytics function. Hence you are getting the error.

Comment: If I need row_number() how can we generate in Beam SQL, using udaf can we do? any suggestion please?

Comment: Note that BeamSQL has started to support OVER and window clauses: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9198. With this syntax support BeamSQL could implement row_number() in near term.

Comment: Here is a table that lists functions are planed to be implemented: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nUbV45iL_avgAewYYTkyHHJWY8ZaVcFuky-dQ-pcE0M/edit#heading=h.6whiyp3fzu7o